# Is it a risk for a website to display the password hash in the password box after clicking submit?

Tags: security, authentication, hash, passwords

I’ve just had to log in to the website of a large utility company (as a customer).

When I clicked submit, I noticed that a hash of my password was created and displayed in the password box (show password was selected).

I’ve never noticed this before, would it be a security issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: How do you know that it is the hash of your password?

Comment: The password from the browser should never be sent to the server as plain-text. If your password was scrambled before sending, it is a good thing. That way if someone captures the data before it reaches the server, they would not be able to make much sense of it. The website is doing a good job.

Comment: Because it was a really long hex string... WlpyC4HADDp7M... etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very good that it shows the hash. Anyone that logins would be able to get the hash and identify the pattern and cryptography that they use to secure the passwords, this way, being easier to possible hacks and attacks.

If possible, I would inform via support - email for example - about this. Probably, they don't even notice, which would be a mistake and possible problem with people that are not well intentioned.

Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I have a bare minimal understanding of these things but knew it didn’t look right.  The only way they let you contact them is twitter and Facebook  I sent a message with a screenshot through twitter and was told by the customer service person that this is fine and it’s just because I had the ‘show password’ box ticked.  I told her that it was not normal and she should forward it on to the website team... will see what happens!

Comment: You did the right think @Conanthelibrarian ! Hope they fix that! If you found my answer helpful, please, considering accepting it or upvoting! :)

Comment: I did, but as a new user, I got the message ‘yeah thanks for your upvote but you’re too new so we’ll record it but no one will ever know!’

Comment: No problem! It happens! Thanks anyway @Conanthelibrarian

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the  Jonah Hex's answer, if the hash is the client side hash, namely a hash computed on the password and not salted by the server, then anyone watching you log (e.g. if you're in a share screen session, or at a public place where some random person can take a picture of the screen) has your hashed password and your username, and they can use a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to hack your account.

If it's the salted hash, it's not as bad, but still far, far from ideal.

Comment: I’ve just never seen it before, usually the password box blanks out or is replaced by symbols... I’ve no idea whether it was salted or not, just looked out of the ordinary. Thanks for the reply, I’ll upvote but unfortunately I’m too new for it to count :(

Comment: BTW You can try hashing your password with a bunch of hash algorithms and see if any of them matches the hash you see.